# Is there in plpgsql a possibility to get record item names and use them?

Tags: postgresql, variables, record, plpgsql, descriptor

I need to report record items using "raise notice", but including item names.

```
raise notice 'rec=%',r; -- is not very good
```

Is there a possibility to do someting like:

```
declare
  r record;
  itemname varchar(200);
begin
  select * into r from my_table_unknown_structure;

  for itemname in pg_record_item_names(r)
  loop
    raise notice '%=%,itemname,pg_record_item_value(r,itemname);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: To access fields within a record the only currently supported method, AFAIK, is to `hstore(rec)`. Which loses type info. With luck we can improve it using the json support.

Comment: It looks very promising. Probably it solves my problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is based on the CRAIG RINGER's comment, using "hstore" extension.
I would like to promote his comment as the answer.

```
declare
    r record;
    h hstore;
begin
    select * into r from more_joined_tables;
    select * into h from hstore(r);
    raise notice '%',h;
end;
```

OR

```
declare
    r record;
    h record;
begin
    select * into r from price_list;
    for h in select * from each(hstore(r))
    loop
        raise notice '%',h;
    end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a JSON object for each row of the table

```
select row_to_json(t)
from t;
         row_to_json         
-----------------------------
 {"a":1,"b":"a_value"}
 {"a":2,"b":"another_value"}
```

If you need the first row only and want it as set of key/value pairs

```
select *
from json_each ((
    select row_to_json(t)
    from t
    limit 1
))
;
 key |   value   
-----+-----------
 a   | 1
 b   | "a_value"
```

Comment: Good try, but primary, I need it quickly for debugging procedures. When multi-table select with joins returns a record. I really need to display the record, but value-list without column names is untransparent.

Comment: @Hink: Both solutions in my answer show column names.